# Quando usiamo il proverbio "Zucchero e acqua rosa, non guastò mai alcuna cosa"

Tags: proverbs

Quando ed in quali situazioni usiamo il proverbio "Zucchero e acqua rosa, non guastò mai alcuna cosa" ? Cosa significa?

Comment: Per curiosità: dove lo hai letto o sentito?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ho trovato questo riferimento: https://books.google.it/books?id=Irx3oPMEwmUC&pg=PA331&lpg=PA331&dq=Zucchero+e+acqua+rosa,+non+guast%C3%B2+mai+alcuna+cosa&source=bl&ots=gfxU_LHLG1&sig=oiuYXjmGlMwpmLIOc0mb-MMZOZA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwithJ6EjKnRAhWKvRQKHbb3CMkQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=Zucchero%20e%20acqua%20rosa%2C%20non%20guast%C3%B2%20mai%20alcuna%20cosa&f=false

Dovrebbe quindi indicare il fatto che la dolcezza dei modi, quando è sincera, non guasta mai.

Un modo di dire simile credo sia: "con la dolcezza si ottiene tutto".